# Drawing on RelativeLayout's Canvas behind all other views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `RelativeLayout` to absolutely position some standard views (like `TextView`).

What I'd like to do is to draw a custom line on this `RelativeLayout`'s `Canvas` using `Canvas.drawLine` that is drawn *behind* all its other subviews.

These other subviews are added with explicitely defining `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, but I'd like to leave the decision of *where* to paint itself to my custom line.

I tried wrapping this line in a CustomView with overloaded `View.onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method and simply adding the view *without* specifying any `LayoutParams`, so:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
  public CustomView(Context context, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    super(context);
    setClickable(false);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  }
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.i("myapp", "i'm not called! :(")
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, p);
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
CustomView v = new CustomView(MyActivity.this, 0, 0, 100, 100);
relativeLayout.addView(v);
```

... but this `onDraw` method is never called.

Is there a way to make this work?

---

**Edit**: works if I substitute:

```
relativeLayout.addView(v)
```

with

```
relativeLayout.addView(v,
  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(SOME_WIDTH, SOME_HEIGHT));
```

The point is, I know neither `SOME_WIDTH`, nor `SOME-HEIGHT` at that point.

Comment: extend RelativeLayout, not View

Comment: @pskink, this wouldn't be a good, hm, *decompositional* choice for my app's "logic". These lines are important elements on their own and their placement depends on placement of other subviews of a normal Layout.

Comment: hmmm, i dont understand, if it depends on child views then itrrate over them in RelativeLayout and get yheir positions getTop/getLeft etc

Comment: @psink, I *know* the positions. I just want to draw on RL's Canvas freely.

Answer (score 4):

try this custom RelativeLayout:

```
class RL extends RelativeLayout {
    private Paint mPaint;
    public RL(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int cnt = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int l = child.getLeft();
            int t = child.getTop();
            int r = child.getRight();
            int b = child.getBottom();
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                canvas.drawLine(l, t, r, b, mPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawLine(l, b, r, t, mPaint);
            }
        }
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and test it ba adding the following in onCreate() method:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RL(this);
TextView tv;
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "    two    ", "three", "    four    ", "fife");
int i = 0;
for (String string : list) {
    int id = 1000 + i;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (i != 0) {
        params.addRule(RL.BELOW, id - 1);
    }
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextSize(48);
    tv.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
    tv.setText(string);
    rl.addView(tv, params);
    tv.setId(id);
    i++;
}
setContentView(rl);
```

Comment: Hey, this surely works: because you're painting on the `RelativeLayout` in its own `dispatchDraw`. :)

Comment: hmm, this is the most natural solution, why would i draw somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Friend, I want to Zoom the Relative Layout and Draw the line. How to I apply you code with Zoom?

Comment: @reegan29 `RelativLayout#setScale[X|Y]` ?

Comment: I have a Zoom library for zoom Relative layout . I have a button called Enable zoom .. When I enable zoom, the button text change to 'disable zoom' and the zoom only enable . When I click disable zoom button, the drawing is enable. after the zoom enable I can zoom the layout with my drawing .. Please help me bro .. I tried last one week I couldn't able this ..

Answer (score 0):

So.

I ended up creating a `CustomController` which has some methods to calculate position/size and using this controller when creating `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` for each `CustomView(context, controller)`.

I guess you cannot have a subview in a `RelativeLayout` without specifying its `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to call the `super.draw(Canvas)` method after you finished your background in the `onDraw()` method.
That will cause it to draw the children last.